# How to take off all pixels in circle on surface excluding circumference?

Tags: circles, graphing-functions, integer-programming

I've got a coordinate surface with dimensions (800, 600) px

There is a circle on the surface with fixed radius.

How to pull out all pixels in the circle on the surface excluding circumference?

I know the simplest formula of circle `(x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 <= R^2`.

It works, but it takes more performance for execution, because I need to go through all the values (x,y) from surface and put them to equation to comparing.

Also a little remark is that I need to get only whole pixels in circle.

I forgot one method, when are joined lines from one point of circle to another.

Comment: Do you mean that you want all pixels wholly inside the circle ?

Comment: Are $x_0,y_0,r$ integer or real ?

Comment: Yes, only inside. x0, y0 is float

Comment: There are very efficient algorithms for drawing a circle, i.e., determining which pixels lie on a circle, that can be adapted to this application. Search the Internet for something like “DDA for drawing circle.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the row of pixels between $y-1/2$ and $y+1/2$, the intersection of the circle with the slab is obtained by solving

$$(x-x_0)^2+\left(y\pm\frac12-y_0\right)^2=r^2,$$

or

$$x=x_0\pm\sqrt{r^2-\left(y\pm\frac12-y_0\right)^2}.$$

This gives you four values of $x$ and the whole pixels are found in the range

$$\left[\left\lceil \max(x_{--},x_{-+})+\frac12\right\rceil,\left\lfloor\max(x_{+-},x_{++})-\frac12\right\rfloor\right]$$

If some of the roots do not exist, then there is no useful pixel.

Note that this assumes square pixels. Round pixels would make it a little different.

Comment: Can you explain me, why 1/2, why not 1/4 or another value?

Comment: @Daniel: hem, pixels are spaced by one unit.

Comment: Why not 1/4? Does it mean that I don't include pixels with 1/2 of area intersection?

Comment: Are you sure that pixels are devided exactly oat the 1/2 part?

Comment: @Daniel: why this question ? Choose your favorite offset and adapt the equations.